# What's the difference between interactive and non-interactive thread? And performance in different CPU Scheduler?

Tags: multithreading, scheduler, cfs

A scheduler that approximates SRTF, like a multi-level feedback queue design, will tend to favor interactive programs that perform short CPU bursts. Linux's Completely Fair Scheduler sometimes does so, but since it has a different scheduling goal, it often wil not. In which of the following scenarios is **CFS** likely to result in much worse performance for the interactive thread than an **MLFQ-like** scheduler that approximates **SRTF**?

1. running one interactive thread with short CPU bursts that, if running alone, would use very little CPU time and one very CPU-intensive thread that never does I/O
2. running one interactive thread with short CPU bursts that, if running alone, would use very little CPU time and one non-interactive thread with much longer CPU bursts that performs disk I/O frequently
3. running one interactive thread with frequent short CPU bursts that, if running alone, would use most of the available CPU time, and one very CPU-intensive thread that never does I/O
4. running one interactive thread with short CPU bursts and a very large number of CPU-intensive threads that never do I/O

`The correct answers are 3 and 4.`

Why 3 & 4 are correct? What's the difference between interactive and non-interactive thread?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, an interactive thread is one that tends to spend most of its time waiting for I/O, only doing small amounts of computation in between. That is, it mostly responds quickly to inputs rather than doing longer computations.

More broadly speaking, when we speak of interactive programs, we usually mean ones that are primarily responding to some external input. A common scheduling goal is to provide programs like these with higher priority than normal programs to provide at least the appearance of better performance to users waiting for the machine to do something. When thinking about interactivity this way, exact definitions vary --- there are different notions of what counts as an "external input".

For answering this question in particular, we don't actually need to use any definition of "interactive". The reason the question specifies that one thread is interactive is to motivate the question --- this is a case where **SRTF-like** schedulers can do better than **CFS** by identifying interactive threads by their tendency to have short CPU bursts. Rather than relying on us saying the thread is "interactive", we can understand how the **SRTF** scheduling policy will work based on the CPU burst lengths, which we are told explicitly. We can understand how the **CFS** policy will apply by considering that it splits the CPU time approximately fairly between the available threads.

For 1 and 2:
since the interactive thread doesn't use much CPU time overall, it will tend to be run first by **CFS**, but it will also tend to be run first by **SRTF** since it has the shortest CPU bursts

For 3:
**CFS** will end up giving the interactive thread about half the available CPU time (fairly splitting CPU time between the two available threads), but under **SRTF**, it would would always be run first (whenever it could run) because of its shorter CPU burst and would end up getting much more than half the time (since "running alone, [it] would use most of the available CPU")

For 4:
**CFS** will end up giving the interactive thread about 1/N of the available CPU time where N is the total number of threads and we are told that N is very large. Under **SRTF**, the thread would always run first, so it would almost certainly get more than the small sliver of CPU time that 1/N represents

--answer from my professor